# Javascript window.open broken link on server

Tags: javascript, html, hyperlink, window.open

The following functions are working locally but not when I post the file containing them on the server:

```js
function optionOtbutton(){
    if (g_oQuizResults.strScore<100) alert("You did not pass this quiz with 100% accuracy; therefore you will not get a certificate. Click OK, close the browser window and click on the Retry Quiz button.") + end;
    if (g_oQuizResults.strScore=100)
    window.open("Certificate_1.html", target="_self");
}
function optionOtherbutton(){
    if (g_oQuizResults.strScore<100) alert("You did not pass this quiz with 100% accuracy; therefore you will not get a certificate. Click OK, close the browser window and click on the Retry Quiz button.") + end;
    if (g_oQuizResults.strScore=100)
    window.open("Certificate_2.html", target="_self");
```

Here are the buttons that call the functions:

```html
<a href="" onclick="optionOtbutton()"><h4>Occupational Therapy</a>

<a href="" onclick="optionOtherbutton()">Other</a>
```

Basically, when saved locally, it works fine. But when I upload it to the server the first condition of the function works well (meaning, the user is prompted with the alert) but the other half shows a broken link (when I place the mouse over the link the task bar shows me the directory where `Certificate_1.html` and `Certificate_2.html` are located, but does not open the HTML files themselves).

Comment: Have you definitely uploaded the files Certificate_1.html and Certificate_2.html? If it's showing the correct directory, and it worked locally, I see no reason for this to not work.

Comment: usually this happen with me because a case sensitive problem with the server (Certificate_1.html is certificate_1.html) can you check this? or something related to .htaccess file, the page load with or without the "http://" on the address?

Comment: to MyNotes: yes. the files are in the correct directory.

Comment: to Edu Ruiz, I replaced the names with law case names only, but it did not work. Meanwhile, I replaced the onclick=" "  with a button and that worked fine.